# Cloning an array of objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like below defined in my interface:

```
myArray: [{
    id: number;
    item: string;
    checked: boolean;
}]
```

I am trying to clone the array using the below statement:

```
let newArray = myArray.map(x => Object.assign({},x));
```

When I am trying to assign a new array to my original array, I am getting the below error:

```
Type '{ id: number; item: string; checked: boolean; }[]' is not assignable to type
'[{ id: number; item: string; checked: boolean; }]'.
  Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer
```

It looks like the array of objects is being transformed to an object of array.

Comment: `myArray` is defined as a [*tuple*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), not an *array*, type. You've said it should have exactly one entry. `.map` makes no such guarantee. Your initial type is probably wrong, or if you do only have one entry you don't need to `.map`.

Comment: Change `myArray: [{
    id: number;
    item: string;
    checked: boolean;
}]` to `myArray: {
    id: number;
    item: string;
    checked: boolean;
}[]`

Comment: guys one of you should answer with that, not comment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem you're having lies in the difference between tuple and list types in TypeScript. Consider the following example [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggzgFQK5gDbQLxQNoDskC2ARhAE4C6A3AFDWiSxwymkCGIUW%20xZ2Vt6YFAIhmbUQC5GY9pxz9Bw0S3YAhKfGRpM8ylAD0%20qMAAWASzhQA9rmhlSV0nGpA):

```js
type AsTuple = [number];

type AsArray = number[];

let myArrayA: AsArray = [];
let myArrayB: AsTuple = []; // This one errors
```

Why does the second one error? It's because `AsArray` is an array of numbers, whereas `AsTuple` is a tuple where the first (and only) item in the tuple is a number. An empty array doesn't conform to the type `AsTuple`; it must be a single item array.

In your example, you have:

```js
myArray: [{
    id: number;
    item: string;
    checked: boolean;
}]
```

It defines `myArray` as a tuple type - it can have one item, which is an object. You could correct it by making it an an array type:

```js
myArray: {
    id: number;
    item: string;
    checked: boolean;
}[]
```

You can see an example in [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEC4YG8BQMRMAlgCY5gCucARgKYoDchxJU9cO0KJYA5i2IxgAC3rAA1vQoxaIEABt66MCwC%20AbQC6MALwwdLfMthh6Ad1QYE%20%20MjSYAdHHQAHABQAPfQD4YAPK0AFYSUE7oEBAk-GAeuOoANF4AlClMQA).